# how do I perform permutation testinging for a prediction model developed within caret package (R)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, permutation-test, elastic-net

I'm fairly new to data science/StackExchange, so please excuse any faux pas

I'm trying to perform permutation testing for a chosen ML algorithm (an elastic-net logistic regression) to derive a p-value.

I've trained the prediction model within caret.

Is it possible to perform a permutation test within caret (or is there a way I can do this outside of caret)?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks, Graham